# How to edit the Pandas DataFrame as per the Required Template?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

[image: This is the Original DataFrame.]
[image: Edit the Original DataFrame into this Format]

How to Edit the DataFrame in the first table to the form in the second table?

Comment: Hi. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @jezrael I am sorry about the formatting. In the future I will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your df is:

```
    Field   A;mean;k    B;mean;k    A;std;k   B;std;k
0   ct1     1           2           3         1
1   ct2     4           5           6         7
```

---

```
df.set_index('Field',inplace=True)
df.columns = df.columns.str.split(';',expand=True, n=1)
```

---

```
df=df.unstack().swaplevel(0,2).unstack().T
```

---

**Result:**

```
Field ct1               ct2
      mean;k    std;k   mean;k  std;k
A     1         3       4       6
B     2         1       5       7
```

To see what's actually happening in each steps just print df at every steps.

You basically need your df to look like this so that you can convert it into your desired form:

```
           Field
A  mean;k  ct1      1
           ct2      4
B  mean;k  ct1      2
           ct2      5
A  std;k   ct1      3
           ct2      6
B  std;k   ct1      1
           ct2      7
```

Swap your 0th level with 2nd level i.e 1st column(A,B) with third(ct1,ct2) column

```
Field           
ct1    mean;k  A    1
ct2    mean;k  A    4
ct1    mean;k  B    2
ct2    mean;k  B    5
ct1    std;k   A    3
ct2    std;k   A    6
ct1    std;k   B    1
ct2    std;k   B    7
```

Then unstacking them again you will get:

```
                A   B
Field           
ct1   mean;k   1    2
      std;k    3    1
ct2   mean;k   4    5
      std;k    6    7
```

Comment: This is a Brilliant solution :) , +1